# Unique partition key or grouping partition key for bulk analysis

Tags: sql, cassandra, data-modeling

I want to see every value for every user in a time period.

Should my primary key be `(user_id, timestamp)` such that I hit every node and let the cluster key window things down.

Or should my primary key be `(day_of_year, timestamp)` such that my partition key finds a subset of nodes, and I use the timestamp cluster key to achieve more fine grained control of the time period.

Comment: Your database design should satisfy all your business requirements, not just one report.

Answer (score 1):

You need to estimate the data that a partition created by `(day_of_year, timestamp)` will have. If the partition size goes over 100 MB, then this might bring you problems in the future during repairs. So, if you are at risk of going over 100 MB for partitions like that, then you should go for `(user_id, timestamp)`. It will also distribute effort throughout the nodes instead of concentrating on just one.

To get an idea of the partition size you can run `nodetool cfstats`. In the output, check the value for `Compacted partition maximum bytes`. It's not guaranteed to be the largest partition everywhere, but it will tell you the largest partition size that was compacted on the node where you are running the command.

Comment: I’m aware of the dangers of high-cardinality keys, and the 100MB partition size. Essentially I was wondering what are the trade-offs between a data-scientist’s desire to use every machine in a cluster, and the data-engineer’s desire that very few machines should be active at any given time.

Comment: Personally, I would go for the data scientists' approach. I don't think it's a good approach to overload a node and leaving the others alone.